# c++ pointer of char exception

Tags: c++, pointers, char

when I do this:
char* text;
text = "Hello";
it works but what I'm really doing here is initialising a pointer of char and it can't hold the value "Hello", just the value of an address? If I do the same thing with int, it does not work why?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 1):

A literal string ends up being a pointer to your data section of your program so it is safe. But when you assign an int to a `int*` it is telling the OS to use that memory location which is not safe

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ standard § 2.14.5/8

> 8 Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal has type “array of n const char”, where n is the size of the string as defined below, and has static storage duration

and section 2.14.5/14

> 14 After any necessary concatenation, in translation phase 7 (2.2), ’\0’ is appended to every string literal so that programs that scan a string can find its end.

`"Hello"` is a narrow string literal, it produces

```
static const char __hello_str[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
```

In C++, inherited from C, is the concept of [array-pointer equivalence](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html), which in this context boils down to the fact that an array - or a string literal - will gladly decay into a pointer.

```
char* text;
text = "hello";
```

introduces a static, nul-terminated character array in the data section of the program, and assigns it's address to the char* variable pointer.

Technically, we're violating the `const`ness of the array here, but many compilers allow this because of legacy C code. However, the C++ standard states in Annex C:

> Subclause 2.14.5:
>   The type of a string literal is changed from “array of char” to “array of const char.” The type of a
>   char16_t string literal is changed from “array of some-integer-type” to “array of const char16_t.” The
>   type of a char32_t string literal is changed from “array of some-integer-type” to “array of const char32_t.”
>   The type of a wide string literal is changed from “array of wchar_t” to “array of const wchar_t.”
>   Rationale: This avoids calling an inappropriate overloaded function, which might expect to be able to modify its argument.

The legacy conversions were deprecated some time ago and have been illegal since C++11. The correct way to do this is:

```
const char* text;
text = "hello";  // correct
```

It's unclear whether you were trying to write

```
int* text;
text = "hello";  // error: incompatible types int* vs const char*
```

or whether you were trying to do something like:

```
const int a = 1;
int* ptr;
ptr = &a;  // error: int* vs const int*.
```

Comment: Re "The legacy conversions are deprecated and will in a future version of C++ will presumably become illegal.", conversion of a narrow string literal to `char*` has been invalid since C++11.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 0):

Re the example

```
char* text; text = "Hello";    //! Not OK
```

The string literal has type `char const [6]`, where the 6<sup>th</sup> `char` value is a terminating zero-byte.

Converting that to `char*` is **invalid** as of C++11 and later.

However, in C++98 and C++03 it was valid for backward compatibility with C. There was a special rule for string literals, that allowed dropping the `const`. In C++11 and later you have to keep the `const`-ness (which is more safe because modifying the literal is Undefined Behavior), i.e.

```
char const* text; text = "Hello";
```

Here the string literal decays to a `char const*` pointer that points to the first `char` value, and this pointer value is assigned to `text`.

There is no such implicit conversion from `int` to pointer value. But if you had an array of `int`, that array would convert implicitly to pointer. E.g.,

```
int const a[] = { 2, 7, 1, 8, 2, 8, 1, 8, 2, 8};
int const* p = a;
```